# Python Notebook run automatically periodically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a script in a notebook browser that does some live data analysis, that I would like to run periodically by itself once every few seconds/minutes, rather than I having to do Ctrl+Enter all the time.

Is there any way to achieve this? Do I need any additional plug-ins, and which ones

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to do it:

```
import time
def periodic_work(interval):
    while True:
        #change this to the function you want to call, or paste in the code you want to run
        your_function()
        #interval should be an integer, the number of seconds to wait
        time.sleep(interval)
```

To run once per minute, run a new cell with `periodic_work(60)` -- you should see a closed circle in the top right of the IPython Notebook that indicates the Kernal is busy. If/when you want to stop the live update, hit the Stop button (labeled Interrupt) on the menu bar and wait a second or so. To start it up again, run the cell that calls `periodic_work` again.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to make your cell a function. In another cell, just call time.sleep () in an appropriate loop. You could also have it check for the existence of some external resource to quit, if you don't want to loop an a priori known finite number of times.